# custom template - override plugin template in child theme - issue with scripts

Tags: templates, page-template, wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I'm using a custom template for the single-listing.php from WP Listings.

I've used my own theme (Canvas by woothemes) single post template, and included the wp-listings code. http://pastebin.com/cAYFEruA

The issue I'm having is that my custom single-listing.php is in my child theme directory. Because of this the following code doesn't work because the file paths are different from the plugin code:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_single_listing_scripts');
function enqueue_single_listing_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-listings-single' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-validate', array('jquery'), true, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fitvids', array('jquery'), true, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-listings-single', array('jquery, jquery-ui-tabs', 'jquery-validate'), true, true );
}
```

None of these are loading in my custom template.

What's the best way to include them correctly?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-listings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Provide Proper path to enqueue scripts and styles

Example-

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

then it will work fine

Comment: I've done the same, and unable to get it to work. See edit: http://pastebin.com/cAYFEruA. I even tried it with a full path to the stylesheet, and enqueue is not working.

Comment: Please use wp_enqueue_scripts in your function.php file and also check wp_head() and wp_footer() hook are included correctly

Comment: Still not working at any level - regardless of what I try

Comment: giving you the answer, but it turns out it's a different issue. Will ask a separate question - thanks!